# STM32 decompiler

Tags: hex, reverse-engineering, stm32, decompiler

I found on my pc an old .hex file from a project that I worked a few years ago. The problem is that I couldn find the source code on my pc, and I forgot how my code worked. Can anyone help me to decompile it and to reverse engieneer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open it in `IDA` or in `Ghidra`, they should recognize the file as `intel-hex`. When you open, you should choose the processor - the `CPU` architecture of the file (`ARM`, `TriCore`, `PPC`, ...).

Your chip is `STM32`, so it's supposed to be `32-bit LE ARM`.

Then browse through the code. If the `CPU` architecture is supported by your `IDA`, you can press `F5` to decompile a function. Ghidra supports more `CPU` architectures, so you can just browse through the functions and see the decompilation results in the decompile window.

Comment: And to add to the above - at least in IDA - you may also have to go and define at least the segments that are used in the program, so flash (ROM) and RAM, plus external memories, if any.

Comment: should i use a hex to binary convertor? I tryed IDA but i cannot find the arm arhitecture , and on Ghidra it only shows the instructions , not some decompiled code

Comment: You don't need the converter. Maybe your `IDA` Version doesn't support `ARM`? In `Ghidra` try to select all (`ctrl+a`), and then press `d` (disassemble). Then go to any location and press `ctrl+e` to decompile.